# Angular material autocomplete does not auto close on document blur

Tags: javascript, angularjs, autocomplete, angular-material

Natural behaviour of an input field when you click on the 'body' of the document, is to blur the element. However with the autocomplete directive on desktop this works, but on mobile it never lets you close the menu unless you pick an item or refresh the page.

I thought this was just my setup, however if you run chrome and emulate an iphone 5 it does not close the autocomplete dropdown list when you click outside it.

Is this possible out of the box?

Comment: I've run your test with the demo and clicking outside closes the dropdown - https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/autocomplete

Comment: on a phone @camden_kid

Answer (score 0):

One option is set your css with rule under:

```
.md-scroll-mask{
    display none
}
```

Comment: Your solution will be working, but it's removing the scroll, so if you have a scrollable page you won't be able to scroll down.